# View sorting programmatically

Tags: 7, views

I have a view with grouping (by one field) and sorting by nodequeue weight.
I want to sort the groups as well so I've used hook_views_pre_render and sorted the results array programmatically, but as far as I can see the results aren't rendered as the results array on $view->result order.

What am I missing? Workaround will also be great!
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471361/drupal-sorting-a-view-programmatically

Comment: The link isn't really helpful in my case. The problem was with hook_view_pre_render. When I migrated my custom code to hook_views_post_execute it began to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was hook_views_pre_render, for some reason the markup is already render at this stage (weird..),  when I used the same code in hook_views_post_execute it worked perfectly.